# Installing TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit together

Tags: tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I have TortoiseSVN installed and it works great. Would like to have an equally great interface to things hosted on Git.

1. Is TortoiseGit as good as TortoiseSVN?

   - Can they both be installed without much trouble? Will menus be duplicated? Will stuff be weird? Any experiences with this?

*I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, if that makes any difference.*

Comment: Re #1, in my opinion yes, and having Git more functionalities than SVN, TortoiseGit exposes a lot of them, probably all. Re #2, it worked right away for me, and no icon problems detected. Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, with "_TortoiseSVN 1.9.3, Build 27038 - 64 Bit_" already installed. I installed "_TortoiseGit 2.0.0.0 git version 2.6.1.windows.1_" on top of that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. TortoiseGit has been rewritten in the same style as TortoiseSVN, it looks like some additions and some changes from the outside. It depends more on asking the question if Git is as goot as SVN. Seems they finished porting TortoiseGit, when I last tried it it was around 60% ported.
2. I know that each thing that will be inserted in the system contains the word SVN, so with TortoiseGit that would be Git. They can be used next to each other, although you should watch out with the overlay icons. Just don't mix them up by using them in the same directory...

Just go and try it, nothing can go wrong. :-)

Comment: *Nothing can go wrong*.... right... :p haha. But I guess I will do that then! Really wish they would just put them all together into a nice *Tortoise* application. That would be awesome...

Comment: Different teams, and those great tools being both free is already a good start I would say ;-)

Comment: seriously, why don't the Tortoise* groups get together and build a unified product?  The basics of source control are similar in all of the tools (cvs, arch, darcs, git, hg, svn, bzr, etc).  I use multiple repository types already - why not have a tool adapted to supporting that?  I'd rather have tools that supported urls though, such as git://kernel.org, svn://tigris.org, etc and launch the right tool,

Comment: Yeah, a system that calls a plug-in for an action would be great.

Comment: I am currently using git and SVN on the same projects (to not pollute the company-wide SVN repository with my multi-branches experiments that stay on my non-share git repository). It all works fine except for the overlay icons: they take the 'worst' status from both, and refresh oddly. The rest works very well

Comment: Good to hear, PPC.
As there is only one overlay, it makes sense the File Explorer can only say the files have not been committed - but cannot easily express to which repo type.
What I'd expect is that the sync between a specific repo still shows an accurate status - so if the file is out of sync with the GIT repo  but not the SVN then it would commit nothing to SVN if you asked for an SVN committ and would commit changes to the GIT repo for a GIT comitt.  It is a rare case to have SVN and GIT on the same files/project - typically its dictated by company policy/project code management rules.

Comment: "Yeah, a system that calls a plug-in for an action would be great." Like Eclipse with an EGit-plugin and SVN-Connector-plugin. :-) Yes, I know they can't do everything, I don't mean to start that discussion ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm running windows 7 32bit. I had tortoisesvn for a long time now, and I added tortoise git about a week ago...

So far the only bad thing I noticed is that, sometimes, if I try to open a folder that is svn'ed it takes a few seconds more, but that's it :-)